# An unexpected error occurred with tcp plugin

Tags: tcp, monitoring, logstash, syslog

I made a simple logstash configuration:

#### tcp.conf

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 22
    type => syslog
  }  
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

#### running the configuration:

```
bin/logstash -f tcp.conf
```

#### executing this command:

```
telnet localhost 22
```

#### I get this error:

```
Using milestone 2 input plugin 'tcp'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
Using milestone 1 filter plugin 'syslog_pri'. This plugin should work, but would benefit from use by folks like you. Please let us know if you find bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this plugin.  For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}

+---------------------------------------------------------+
| An unexpected error occurred. This is probably a bug.   |
| You can find help with this problem in a few places:    |
|                                                         |
| * chat: #logstash IRC channel on freenode irc.          |
|     IRC via the web: http://goo.gl/TI4Ro                |
| * email: logstash-users@googlegroups.com                |
| * bug system: https://logstash.jira.com/                |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
The error reported is: 
  Permission denied - bind(2)
```

I am doing this configuration fallow the [Syslog example](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash)

Comment: but 22 is ssh port, not syslog port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Permission denied - bind" means that logstash can't attach itself to the listed port.

Often, this is because you're running logstash as a non-privileged user who cannot access ports numbered below 1024.

In your case, you're trying to connect to port 22.  As the ssh/scp/sftp port, this seems like an odd place to look for log files.

Comment: ok, I change the port to 8000 and it works, but if I want to check the 22 port? How can I do that?

Comment: logstash is trying to read logs from that port; what logs would you expect to be sitting on the ssh port?  If you really needed to bind to that port, you'd need to shutdown ssh and run logstash as root.  Please don't do either.